# I have a problem when I use Ext.define

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I get the error:

```
events is null or not a object
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.define("com.yx.DflCombo", {
        extend: "Ext.form.field.ComboBox",
        config: {
            name: "dfl",
            fieldLabel: "category"
        },
        constructor: function(config) {
            this.initConfig(config);
            return this;
        }
    });
    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        title: 'Simple Form',
        bodyPadding: 5,
        width: 350,
        items: [Ext.create("com.yx.DflCombo",{})]
    });
});
```

Thanks, Molecule Man!
I try another test like this.

```
Ext.define("com.yx.MyPanel", {
extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
config: {
title: "Clannad"
},
constructor: function(config) {
this.initConfig(config);
this.callParent([config]);
}
});
Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
width: 400,
height: 400,
title: "Key",
items: [Ext.create("com.yx.MyPanel", {})]
});
```

And I get the error:dockedItems is null or not a object!
I just want to know when I define a class that extend an EXTJS class, what should I do?

Comment: Are you sure this is all the code? What is the error line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your code:

1. You don't call `callParent` method in your constructor. It's required when you are extending existing class:

   ```
   constructor: function(config) {
     this.initConfig(config);
     this.callParent([config]);
   }
   ```
2. The `store` config should be specified in combobox' config:

   ```
   items: [Ext.create("com.yx.DflCombo",{
     store: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
   })]
   ```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/yYrkq/).